# Can empty init method in a class initialise the static final variables?

Tags: java, static

I have a class which has static final variables. I want to intialize it at boot up time, not when they are first referenced. Can I have an empty static init() method in the class which will serve the purpose?

Example

```
public class ABC {
   private static final SomeObject abc = new SomeObject();
   //other methods and variables
   public static void init(){
    //empty method
   }
}

public class DEF{
   public class static void main(String[] args) {
     ABC.init();
   }
}
```

Comment: `I want to intialize it at boot up time, not when they are first referenced` - static members are initialized when the class is loaded, not when they are first referenced. Then, in practice, that should not even make a difference. What exactly do you want to achieve? And what do you mean by "boot up time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static block and initialize it there. Your `init()` method might end up initializing them every time you create an object.

```
public class ABC {
   private static final SomeObject abc = new SomeObject();
   //other methods and variables
   static{
       //initialization code.
   }

}

public class DEF{
   public class static void main(String[] args) {
ABC a =new ABC();

   }
}
```